# Adicionar plugin phonegap/cordova

Tags: apache-cordova, plugin

Oi, galera.

Estou tentando desenvolver um APP em phonegap para Android e iOS. O objetivo do APP é:

1) A pessoa terá um botão para acessar a câmera do dispositivo.
2) Quando aparecer a tela de tirar foto do dispositivo, deverá ter uma imagem na tela, tipo um alvo de tiro, algo do tipo. Quando a pessoa clicar pra tirar a foto, o resultado tem que estar com esse alvo (no arquivo jpeg, por exemplo).
3) A foto aparece na tela do APP pra pessoa ver se gostou...
4) .. Se ela gostou, ela clica num botão que faz aparecer aquelas opções de compartilhamento nativo do dispositivo.

Eu já consegui (1) e (3). Copiei este código:
"https://gist.github.com/dhavaln/2238017"

O código está EXATAMENTE igual a esse link do gitHub, a única coisa que fiz foi deixar apenas um botão que acesse a câmera (porque o código da acesso às imagens e galeria do dispositivo, não preciso disso).

A minha dificuldade é (e gostaria mesmo de entender isso) como eu faço pra adicionar um plugin. O plugin de compartilhamento achei aqui:
http://plugins.telerik.com/nativescript?page=1&search=camera&collection=plugins_telerik_nativescript

e o plugin mesmo está em:
http://plugins.telerik.com/nativescript/plugin/social-share

Quando uso o código no prompt de comando (estou usando o windows7... mas vou configurar também num OpenSUSE Tumbleweed esta semana) "phonegap plugin add nativescript-social-share" ou o mesmo comando só que com "cordova", aparece a mensagem "Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin 'package'. Please try adding it again."

Na verdade existe um arquivo plugin.xml dentro de "/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/" mas parece ser incompatível... criei um plugin.xml com o código tirado de:
https://github.com/GrumpySailor/cordova-plugin-device-rotation-vector/blob/master/plugin.xml

mas sem sucesso ainda.

Muito do que quero fazer e com certeza vou precisar mais no futuro estão "prontos", só preciso adicionar plugins. Procurei vários tutoriais na internet, o que mais gostei foi:
http://www.thecodebakers.org/2011/03/licao-1-praparando-o-terreno.html

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

O que eu fiz para criar o projeto que estou tentando fazer isso (meu primeiro!)
na linha de comando fiz "phonegap create HelloW com.eu.hello HelloWorld"

Foi criado bonitinho, depois fiz "phonegap platform add android" e "phonegap platform ios" (que parece não ser possível no windows, mas foram instalados arquivos mesmo assim)

Depois troquei os arquivos css para os meus e o arquivo index.js tirei e direcionei para o "meu_js.js". Adicionei o HTML da camera (primeiro link) no html e o JS (primeiro link também) nesse "meu_js.js".

Para testar o APP estou utilizando um MotoE2, com aquele aplicativo PhoneGap, que permite conexão via "phonegap serve"

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

O que eu sei:
Eu domino completamente HTML5, CSS3 e PHP. Tenho algum entendimento básico de javaScript e Python, e estou começando a estudar Java.

Lembrando que é meu PRIMEIRO contato com o phonegap... se possível enviem referências onde aprenderam para eu me aprofundar também.

Desde já, muito obrigado! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adicionar um plugin basta usar o seguinte comando:

```
[phonegap][cordova] plugin add <nome do plugin>
```

Cada plugin tem seus métodos e objetos próprios, por isso é importante verificar antes se ele oferece os recursos necessário (e como acessá-los).

O plugin  de compartilhamento social que você especificou parece que só é compatível com a plataforma do Telerik, pois não há indicação de compatilidade com o Cordova/Phonegap; além disso, tentei instalar no Cordova e obtive erros, certamente o mesmo que houve com você.

Sugiro que dê uma olhada no site ngCordova, tem uma coleção muito boa de plugins, inclusive de social sharing: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/

Comment: realmente você tem razão... estava olhando plugins para outro framework. Bom, tentei instalar esse e deu certo/errado. Deu errado porque aparece a mensagem "Error: Path must be a string. Received false". Deu certo porque apareceu um diretório do plugin e as mensagens até o android parecem ok... (estou usando windows7, do trabalho). Vou tentar desenvolver o compartilhamento mais tarde e caso dê certo te aviso (dando tua resposta como solução rs)

Comment: Não deu certo não... Eu fiz tudo o que tava nos readme.md e tal, segui as orientações do Cordova e Phonegap, alterando a whitelist-plugin, mas acabou que os botões que antes já funcionavam acionando a câmera agora não funcionam. O negócio é que os "tutoriais" por aí dizem pra acrescentar um trecho do código, mas não dizem em qual arquivo. Falam pra dar permissões e tal, mas não dizem onde são feitas as permissões. Por exemplo, a tag meta com Content-Security-Policy, coloquei o que eles falam e parou de funcionar tudo :/

Comment: Os códigos podem ficar em qualquer arquivo, seja no index.html ou num arquivo .js externo, fica a critério do programador. Quanto à tag Content-Security-Policy, por enquanto pode tirar ou deixar comentada, só vai servir mesmo pra segurança quando for publicar o app.

Comment: Nada feito... não funciona de jeito nenhum. :/